# datetime.timedelta in google charts line chart

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-visualization, jinja2, timedelta

I'm struggling to use a datetime.timedelta value as the y-axis in my line chart.

Here is what I have:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Day');
data.addColumn('timedelta', 'Time Average');

data.addRow(['Oct-20', {{ timedeltaObject }})]);
```

I am guessing the graph does not render due to the invalid type. I need to use time as a value for my y-axis, specifically only hours and minutes. Say on `Oct-20`, I spent 2 hours and 5 minutes doing X. It should plot that value on the graph.

I know it is possible to plot a datetime object but I specifically need a time value not a date value.

Comment: if you're invoking a python object in your Jinja template, don't you need to wrap it in `{{ }}` or something?

Comment: Yes, it's like that in my code. I'll edit the question for clarity.

Comment: can you insert `console.log({{ timedeltaObject}})` and see what jinja is rendering the object as? (I don't know if Jinja is calling `__repr__()` or `__str__` or whatever on it. Also please add a Jinja/Jinja2 tag since it is a factor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it to work, instead of passing a timedelta object through Jinja, in my python code, I get the hours and minutes from the timedelta object and add them to a list `[hours, minutes, seconds]` with appropriate values.

Then in the googleVisualization I use `data.addColumn('timeofday', 'Time Average');` and pass in my list.

Note: this approach only works for values under 24 hours.

Comment: why not just subclass timedelta in the controller, override/overload the method Jinja uses to parse the timedelta object to return what you need?

Comment: Because this is a very specific case in a large project where it will most likely never be used again. So I wouldn't want to globally override how Jinja parses objects such as timedelta.

Comment: then I would subclass timedelta, and add a separate method like `def render_method(self): return <a correct representation of the delta>` and call `{{ newtimedelta.render_method() }}`